# couchdb doesn't start

Tags: gentoo, sabayon

I installed couchDB under Sabayon with help of Rigo and followed this instruction ( http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/source.html ):

```
xyz@wp01 ~ $ su
Password: 
wp01 xyz # chown -R couchdb:couchdb /etc/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chown -R couchdb:couchdb /var/lib/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chown -R couchdb:couchdb /var/log/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chown -R couchdb:couchdb /var/run/couchdb
chown: cannot access ‘/var/run/couchdb’: No such file or directory
wp01 xyz # chmod -R 0770 /etc/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chmod -R 0770 /var/lib/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chmod -R 0770 /var/log/couchdb
wp01 xyz # chmod -R 0770 /var/run/couchdb
chmod: cannot access ‘/var/run/couchdb’: No such file or directory

$ sudo -i -u couchdb couchdb -b
Password: 
Sorry, user xyz is not allowed to execute '/sbin/nologin -c couchdb -b' as couchdb on wp01.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: add an entry for xyz if that is your username in sudoers for couchdb `xyz ALL = (couchdb) /path/to/couchdb`

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a problem with your `sudo` permissions, not necessarily anything wrong with couchDB itself.

Check your [`sudoers`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) file, and make sure your user has the correct permissions.

Note that `su` and `sudo` use different mechanisms to manage permissions - which is why you were able to use `su` earlier, but encountered the error when trying to use `sudo`.

---

To allow user xyz to freely use sudo, add this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
xyz ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

User xyz will then be prompted for **their password** (not the root password), and then allowed to continue.

I you want to skip the password prompt completely, use this instead:

```
xyz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

There are other options available as well, that will give the access to all member of a group instead of just a particular user, or to restrict which commands they are allowed to run with sudo - but this should be enough to get you going.

One final note - you should always use the [`visudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html) command to edit `/etc/sudoers`, because it will do a syntax check on the file before actually saving your changes. Using a regular text editor will let you save an invalid file, potentially breaking sudo on your machine and locking you out from fixing it (if you needed to use `sudo` to edit the file, for example)

Comment: How do I change the sudo permission in that file?
     
    # User privilege specification
    root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

    # Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
    # %wheel        ALL=(ALL) ALL

    # Same thing without a password
    #%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

    # Samples
    # %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
    # %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

    #Added by Sabayon Installer
    %wheel  ALL=ALL

Comment: @user977828 I've updated my answer to give more information.

Answer (score -1):

Solution (taken from http://praxis.edoceo.com/howto/couchdb)

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb start
$ curl http://your.localhost:5984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"0ca30c5deb1cc6a6eb631f2d6b420934","version":"1.3.1","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation","version":"1.3.1"}}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually address the issue of the user not having `sudo` permissions.